# why database url has to be in a specific format in jdbc?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

As mentioned in oracle documentation, the database url needs to be in format "jdbc:subprotocol:subname: in DriverManager.getConnection() function. The first and most obvious question is why not such a simple way as, for example, "C:\myDatabase.db"?

Comment: What if you are accessing it remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split each component in the URL, you can understand why we need it in that format.

1. there are many databases each with it's own proprietary way of storing information. And only a specific driver can understand and interpret that proprietary information. So, we need the subprotocol to be oracle/mysql/etc.
2. there are may type of drivers just for oracle. Please check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html where you can have thin/oci/etc which go into the subname.
3. As Sotirios mentioned, the case where the database is not in your C:\ and is in somebody else's server - so we need a host, which then naturally mandates for a port as well.
4. Even in that server, the same port, one database 'server' can provide services for multiple databases (or services). So, we need the database name in the URL as well.

Answer (score 1):

Java is operating system agnostic and a format such is "C:\myDatabase.db" is operating system specific. It would not work, for example, to connect to an Oralce DBMS running on Solaris. They are also trying to make it DBMS independent. Not all DBMS systems use the same database/table organization of systems like MySQL. Considering the complexity of the problem trying to solve, their solution is actually rather simple.

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC-Url is an URL an Uniform Ressource Identifier. This means have to follow a syntax.
You can rewrite `C:\myDatabase.db` to an URI too `file:/c:/myDatabase.db`.

In fact for the Windows-Explorer booth are the same, but a webbrowser can only understand the URL-form.

Back to URL:
An [url follows a syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier). The first part is the protocol (`file`)
This will be separated by a `:` from the prootocoll specific part.

For `file`-URIs, this will be a Path starting with the root-directory `/` followed by folders separated by `/`

For JDBC-Urls,  the only common part is the scheme (`jdbc`) and the separator `:`.

In your example you use a local file. But how would you specifiy a database running on another server? You will have to create another way. So you may start like this:

- `jdbc:` the schema
- `mydatabasesystem:` this may say "This is an JDBC-Url for 'ydatabbasesystem' and I know the following syntax.
- `localfile:` I will use a local file and the followin part is the syntax for localfiles
- `/c:/myDatabase.db` There is my file

This will lead to a jdbc-Url:

```
jdbc:mydatabasesystem:localfile:/c:/myDatabase.db
```

Imaging your database may be connected via network.. This may be written like:

```
jdbc:mydatabasesystem:remoteserver:servername?username=user&password=secret
```

You see, if you write a generic way to connect to databses of different manufacturers, youwill have to create a common wy to connect to the database. This will lead to something like a JDBC-url.

Comment: Thank you so much. I picked a few new tips from your answer